# Custom sort on two columns simultaneously Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I have a data frame like this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[3333311,3455572,6464544,2323322,2222111,4333311,5454566,3321767],'A':['12 days','35 days','36 days','56 days','54 days','44 days','56 days','54 days'],'B':['6 days','31 days','33 days','46 days','44 days','16 days','41 days','42 days'],'Percentage':[0.41,0.36,0.36,0.42,0.25,0.56,0.25,0.42]})

              id        A         B       Percentage
    1       3333311   12 days   6 days    0.41
    3953    3455572   35 days   31 days   0.36
    46458   6464544   36 days   33 days   0.36
    39378   2323322   56 days   46 days   0.42
    115880  2222111   54 days   44 days   0.25
    115882  4333311   44 days   16 days   0.56
    118882  5454566   56 days   41 days   0.25
    118884  3321767   54 days   42 days   0.42
```

I want to sort it first on Percentage.

Then when a tie breaker comes, it should sort on A and B simultaneously as

```
     if A.iloc[1] < A.iloc[2]
      and B.iloc[1] < B.iloc[2]
then df.iloc[2] should come first and vice versa.


But      if A.iloc[1] < A.iloc[2]
         and B.iloc[1] > A.iloc[2]

    or   if A.iloc[1] > A.iloc[2]
         and B.iloc[1] < A.iloc[2]
```

Expected output will be like this :

```
         id        A          B       Percentage
115882  4333311   44 days   16 days   0.56
39378   2323322   56 days   46 days   0.42
118884  3321767   54 days   42 days   0.42
1       3333311   12 days   6 days    0.41
46458   6464544   36 days   33 days   0.36
3953    3455572   35 days   31 days   0.36
118882  5454566   56 days   41 days   0.25
115880  2222111   54 days   44 days   0.25
```

Now here on 0.25 percentage tie breaker, there is the condition :
             if A.iloc[118882] > A.iloc[115880]
             and B.iloc[118882] < B.iloc[115880]

Here we will perform other operations and consider other aggregations.

**Can we do it by sorted function with cmp Parameter ?**

Comment: Please show expected output

Comment: @DeepSpace I have edited my query. Now you can check .

Answer (score 0):

This is what I propose,

```py
# removing 'days' string from columns
df.A = df.A.apply(lambda x: x.split()[0])
df.B = df.B.apply(lambda x: x.split()[0])

# sorting by values
df = df.sort_values(by='B').sort_values(by='A').sort_values(by='Percentage', ascending=False)

# adding in 'days' string back to the values of col A & col B
df.A = df.A.apply(lambda x: str(x)+' days')
df.B = df.B.apply(lambda x: str(x)+' days')

print(df)
        id        A        B  Percentage
5  4333311  44 days  16 days        0.56
7  3321767  54 days  42 days        0.42
3  2323322  56 days  46 days        0.42
0  3333311  12 days   6 days        0.41
1  3455572  35 days  31 days        0.36
2  6464544  36 days  33 days        0.36
4  2222111  54 days  44 days        0.25
6  5454566  56 days  41 days        0.25
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I have changed the dataframe and also given the expected output as well. Can you look into it, now ?

Comment: @user9419602 i made the changes, check it now

Comment: How can I apply for the condition when the tie breaker comes.

Comment: Any clue for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can split the sorting and the operation that you want to perform in two different steps.

Get the sorted dataframe as :

```
sorted_df = df.sort_values(['Percentage', 'A', 'B'])
```

But to perform the operations that you want based on the condition, sort just based on percentage. Create another array perc_prev which contains the value of the previous column and use it to find out the indexes of ties

```
df_perc_sorted = df.sort_values('Percentage')
perc_prev = np.hstack(([-1], df['Percent'].values[1:]))
# use the boolean value in the tie array to figure out if there was a tie
tie = perc_prev == df['Percetange']
# similarly create boolean columns to figure out the condition you need
```

Comment: Hey, did you get this  ?